# Route query params in Aurelia app

Tags: aurelia

I have a simple literally one page (at the moment) application built using Aurelia. I am trying to get the query parameters in the activate method as stated here: [Aurelia Docs](http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/framework/1.0.0-beta.1.2.4/doc/article/cheat-sheet) in the Screen Activation Lifecycle section, however none of my query params are showing up as properties on the params parameter for the function. How do I get the query parameters from the URL in Aurelia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that if you do not have push state configured with aurelia then your query string must come after the /#/ part of your URL.
ie: 
`http://example.com/#/?[myquerystuff]`